# ga tracker function does nothing

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am attempting to log the current tracker info to the console as per the Analytics documentation:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-80990893-7', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

ga(function(tracker) {
  // Logs the tracker created above to the console.
  console.log('test');
  console.log(tracker);
});
```

Nothing is actually outputted to the console. It's as if the function is not even executing. Why is this not working when I've literally copy and pasted from their docs?

Comment: Can you use Chrome Devtools set a break point before ga('create...)? Or simply insert `debugger` before it? Does the breakpoint work?

Comment: How long ago did you create the Google analytics account (takes 24 -48 hours) for it to start logging data.   Are you checking the Real-time reports it can take 24 hours for data to appear in the standard reports.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- Code is working fine at my end, please see the above screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Please install and enable **Google** Tag Assistant from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) and start record.

Two things always remember.

- put your **ga** code in always `<head></head>` tag.
- don't put your **ga** code any core function like create one php function and define `<script>ga code is here</script>` and exicute it later. >> **It's totaly wrong way because exicution is skip your ga code.**

Let's go with your question.

- I have noticed your analytics code working fine.
- Google Tag Assistance result as per follow for your code.
- One page view event or tracks found.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to disable ad/tracking blockers ;)

I know that this is an old thread, however, it was the only one I found about this issue and as the others stated the code is actually correct. However, the reason it did not work for me was that I forgot to disable tracking protection.